# Thymelaf and Spring Security - custom SpEL expression

Tags: spring, spring-security, thymeleaf, spring-el

I'm using Thymeleaf with spring security.
In html code I'm checking user role:

```
<li class="has-sub" sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"> 
</li>
```

but in spring I implemented own `CustomSecurityExpressionRoot` so I can use in controller for example

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAccess('PERMISSION')")
```

It is possible to connect Thymeleaf to be able to use `hasAccess` (and others) methods from my `CustomSecurityExpressionRoot`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have put the logic in a singleton Spring bean:

```java
@Component
public class AccessEvaluator {
    public boolean hasAccess(Authentication authentication, String permission) {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

And then in Thymeleaf code:

```xml
<li th:if="${@accessEvaluator.hasAccess(#request.userPrincipal, 'PERMISSION')}"> 
</li>
```

Comment: That is correct answer. Only one disadvantage of that idea is multimpe hasAccess implementation (for Thymeleaf and spring [controllers, etc.])

Comment: Why would you need multiple implementations? You can use the same from both locations. They both execute the expression and there shouldn't be any difference. What is mentioned here is actually also the recommended approach by the Spring Security Team, implementing and wiring a custom security expression root has been made more difficult in favor of this approach.

Answer (score 1):

I used something similar to the posted answer with getting the authentication that way:

```
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class AccessEvaluator {

    public boolean hasAccess(String pageName) {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        return ((MyUserPrincipal) auth.getPrincipal()).getAccessOnPage(pageName);
    }

}
```

And call it as below:

```
<li th:if="${@accessEvaluator.hasAccess('ACT')}" >
    <p> I have access on ACT page </p>
</li>
```